# Why does chrome alias command work only when I call it from root location?

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, git-bash

Using git-bash on Windows 10, I have tried to make a new alias called "chrome". It supposes to open the web browser.
Don't know why it only works when I call the command from the root location.
My brackets alias works just fine.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your path is relative in the chrome alias. That is, there's no leading `/`. Without a leading `/`, bash will assume you're looking for a folder called `c` in your current working directory. If you add the `/` at the beginning (like you did for `brackets`), bash knows to start its path at root. If your current working directory *is* root, then bash will find the chrome executable correctly - that's why it works from that location.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at the difference between the alias `brackets`, which is made to expand to an *absolute* pathname, and the alias `chrome`, which is made to expand to a *relative* pathname.

Hint: There is a missing leading `/` slash in the definition of the alias `chrome`.

Comment: omg. it's so obvious now! it's like I was not looking.
thank you very much for the solution!